# How to print matplotlib histogram coef logistic regression?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm learning deep learning and I would like to print this histogram with matplotlib: 
[image]

from this code who print the data :

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
print(lr.coef_)
```

who prints :

```
[[-0.150896    0.23357229  0.00669907  0.3730938   0.100852   -0.85258357]]
```

edit: 
I tried the basic hist but I don't understand the output :

`plt.hist(lr.coef_) 
plt.show()`

but i got : [image]

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like all you need is a bar chart

Comment: I tried `plt.hist(lr.coef_)
plt.show()` but i got : https://i.imgur.com/Sox9DX4.jpg

Comment: What does that produce? You should edit your question with this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation (*".. Compute and draw the histogram of .."*), `pl.hist` bot calculates and plots a histogram from the raw data. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
data = np.random.normal(size=1000)

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(121)
pl.hist(data)
```

What you want is the `pl.bar` function:

```
# Your data
data = np.array([-0.150896, 0.23357229, 0.00669907, 0.3730938, 0.100852, -0.85258357])
labels = ['as','df','as','df','as','df']

ax=pl.subplot(122)
pl.bar(np.arange(data.size), data)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.size))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Combined this produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the usage of hist and bar correctly. hist is to give the frequency distribution of the data directly, while the bar is simply to give the height bar of a column or row of data.

Comment: Code example would be helpful here. This observation may be more appropriate as a comment.